# How can I extract a sub string from an variable containing xml data in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to PHP programming and will need help. I have a variable $output which store an XML response received from a server. How can I assigned the "value" data to a variable. For example, $devicesn = "db00-0030-6602-xxxx". Bellow is the XML response I get when I echo the $output variable and use "view source" on a browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<simsrv version="1.0" msg_type="response">
<header>
    <param name="SN" value="0" />
    <param name="Domain" value="default" />
    <param name="User" value="admin" />
    <param name="Cmd" value="GetDeviceInfo" />
    <param name="Retries" value="0" />
    <param name="Timeout" value="5000" />
    <param name="Timestamp" value="NA" />
    <param name="AuthInfo" value="39ef0f02a9f4d5799481a8d6f2897a0b" />
    <param name="ErrorCode" value="SUCCESS" />
    <param name="ErrorInfo" value="NA" />
    <param name="ProcessTime" value="1" />
</header>
<GetDeviceInfo>
    <param name="BeginDeviceId" value="0" />
    <param name="MaxGetCount" value="2" />
    <param name="No" value="0" />
    <param name="DeviceId" value="1" />
    <param name="DeviceSn" value="db00-0030-6602-xxxx" />
    <param name="DeviceAlias" value="DWG-16A" />
    <param name="DeviceType" value="DWG2000F " />
    <param name="MaxPortCount" value="16" />
    <param name="AdminStatus" value="ENABLED" />
    <param name="RunStatus" value="COMM_FAIL" />
</GetDeviceInfo>
<GetDeviceInfo>
    <param name="BeginDeviceId" value="0" />
    <param name="MaxGetCount" value="2" />
    <param name="No" value="1" />
    <param name="DeviceId" value="2" />
    <param name="DeviceSn" value="db00-0030-1501-xxxx" />
    <param name="DeviceAlias" value="DWG-16B" />
    <param name="DeviceType" value="DWG2000B " />
    <param name="MaxPortCount" value="16" />
    <param name="AdminStatus" value="ENABLED" />
    <param name="RunStatus" value="ACTIVE" />
</GetDeviceInfo>
</simsrv>
```

Comment: Do you want one specific or all <param> tags in Variables?

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703530/extract-xml-elements-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Best way is the xml using simplexml_load_string and then just use it as an object.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_string($output)
$devicesn = $xml-> GetDeviceInfo[0]-> DeviceSn;
echo $devicesn;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML makes XML handling in PHP very simple (assuming you don't need all the frills etc.), this example loads the already retrieved content and then does a `foreach` for each device in the input.  Then for each device it retrieves a few of the details using XPath (to find the details with the correct tag in `name`)

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xmlText =<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<simsrv version="1.0" msg_type="response">
<header>
    <param name="SN" value="0" />
    <param name="Domain" value="default" />
    <param name="User" value="admin" />
    <param name="Cmd" value="GetDeviceInfo" />
    <param name="Retries" value="0" />
    <param name="Timeout" value="5000" />
    <param name="Timestamp" value="NA" />
    <param name="AuthInfo" value="39ef0f02a9f4d5799481a8d6f2897a0b" />
    <param name="ErrorCode" value="SUCCESS" />
    <param name="ErrorInfo" value="NA" />
    <param name="ProcessTime" value="1" />
</header>
<GetDeviceInfo>
    <param name="BeginDeviceId" value="0" />
    <param name="MaxGetCount" value="2" />
    <param name="No" value="0" />
    <param name="DeviceId" value="1" />
    <param name="DeviceSn" value="db00-0030-6602-xxxx" />
    <param name="DeviceAlias" value="DWG-16A" />
    <param name="DeviceType" value="DWG2000F " />
    <param name="MaxPortCount" value="16" />
    <param name="AdminStatus" value="ENABLED" />
    <param name="RunStatus" value="COMM_FAIL" />
</GetDeviceInfo>
<GetDeviceInfo>
    <param name="BeginDeviceId" value="0" />
    <param name="MaxGetCount" value="2" />
    <param name="No" value="1" />
    <param name="DeviceId" value="2" />
    <param name="DeviceSn" value="db00-0030-1501-xxxx" />
    <param name="DeviceAlias" value="DWG-16B" />
    <param name="DeviceType" value="DWG2000B " />
    <param name="MaxPortCount" value="16" />
    <param name="AdminStatus" value="ENABLED" />
    <param name="RunStatus" value="ACTIVE" />
</GetDeviceInfo>
</simsrv>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xmlText );

foreach ( $xml->GetDeviceInfo as $device ) {
    $deviceSn = $device->xpath("param[@name='DeviceSn']/@value");
    $deviceAlias = $device->xpath("param[@name='DeviceAlias']/@value");
    echo "DeviceSn=".(string)$deviceSn[0].
            " Alias=".(string)$deviceAlias[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```

With the sample data, this produces...

```
DeviceSn=db00-0030-6602-xxxx Alias=DWG-16A
DeviceSn=db00-0030-1501-xxxx Alias=DWG-16B
```

You can fetch all of the details and build an associative array of them using...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xmlText );
$devices = [];
foreach ( $xml->GetDeviceInfo as $device ) {
    $newDevice = [];
    foreach ( $device->param as $element )   {
        $newDevice[(string)$element['name']] = (string)$element['value'];
    }
    $devices[] = $newDevice;
}
print_r($devices);
```